# Android: how can i change scan range of zxing sdk?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

Hi i need to scan 50 char long code 128C, but the default rnage of scaner is to small for my code so i need to customize it for the length of barcode.

How can i do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraManager.java) if you change the variables

```
  private static final int MIN_FRAME_WIDTH = 240;
  private static final int MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT = 240;
  private static final int MAX_FRAME_WIDTH = 480;
  private static final int MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT = 360;
```

you simply set the values and like that you can change the reading range.So it would be able read fast the long barcodes.

hope it will help